# F_OSC definition for Uart using PIC18f

Tags: pic, uart, pll

**PIC18f67j11.**
For F_OSC which one i have to use: My crystall oscillator frequency or the real frequency oscillator including my PLL modifications?

I'm trying to match the baudRate of the UART and doesn't work. i've tried all  reg configurations and baudRate formulas but none of them seems to work.

I'm using a 20MHz external crystall (connected in OSC1 and OSC2) with maximum PLL (OSCTUNE.TUN = 01111) xtal for a 4800bit/s to measure energy by the MCP35F501 meter CI.

[image: Oscilator Clock Diagram]

Here is the clock code selection:

```
`
#define F_OSC                           20000000 
#define FOSC_PLL                        20000000 * 4  
#define FCY                             F_OSC / 4 
`

`// seleciona clock
    OSCCON  = 0xF0;               // INTOSC = 8MHz; SCS = 00: default primary oscillator
    OSCTUNE = 0b01011111;         // PLL = ON; TUN = 011111: Maximum frequency`
```

And my UART config:

```
`
void configureUart(unsigned char uart, unsigned long baudRate) {
` 

    RCSTA2bits.SPEN = 1;
    RCSTA2bits.CREN   = 1;           // Habilita recepção
    TRISGbits.TRISG1 = 0;
    TRISGbits.TRISG2 = 1;
    TXSTA2bits.BRGH = 0;        //Low Speed Mode (baud = 8bits)
    TXSTA2bits.SYNC = 0;        // 0 = Asynchronous Mode
    TXSTA2bits.TX9 = 0;         //Transmissão feita em 8 bits
    RCSTA2bits.RX9 = 0;         //Recepção feita em 8 bit
    BAUDCON2bits.BRG16 = 1;     //16bit Baud Rate Generator 

    TXSTA2bits.TXEN = 1;        // Habilita transmissão
    UART2_RX_INT_EN = 1;        //
    UART2_RX_PRIORITY  = 0;     // Baixa prioridade de interrupção

    baudRate = 1050;//(unsigned long)(FOSC_PLL / (baud_rate * 16)) - 1; TRYING TO MATCH MANUALY TO VALIDATE THE PROTOCOL :#
    // Calcula o novo valor para o registro de configuração do baud-rate
    SPBRGH2 = baudRate >> 8;   // Atualiza BRG da UART1
    SPBRG2 = baudRate;         // ...  
}

`
```

Comment: On way to examine what the baud rate actually is to make a loop that transmits a 0x55 character over and over on the output.  With one start bit and one stop bit, this is effectively a square wave of alternating bit times that you can measure with an oscilloscope

Comment: I can't see clearly from your description which of the many possible oscillator configurations you are using. You mention a 20MHz, is that an external crystal? If so, you can't use PLL (according to my understanding of the datasheet). Also, the datasheet describes OSCTUNE.TUN as affecting only the internal RC oscillator. Can you show the code with your configuration bit settings, any oscillator register settings, and also confirm whether or not you have an external crystal?

Comment: I'm using a 20MHz external crystall. I've uploaded a pic with the Clock diagram where that seems the Primary oscillator can be multiplied times 4.

Comment: See the [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/microchiptechnology_39932D-346424.pdf) page 487 -> PLL Input Frequency Range -> Max 12 Mhz. The part is a 48Mhz (max) part.

Comment: I make FOSC_PLL = 20MHz x 4 and is working well:

`baudRate = (FOSC_PLL / (baud_rate * 16)) - 1;  //FOSC_PLL = 80MHz.`

What can happen if i  mantain the Pll over the maximum?

Comment: Travel outside the bounds of the datasheet at your own risk. All is apparently not well or I doubt you would have asked this question. I'm not saying either way if it is your problem or not, but you should consider it. Why don't you try operating at 20Mhz without the PLL and see what happens?

Comment: I tried. Worked very well too but this extra clock will help me a lot. Even so, all your information helped me a lot and will make more tests if i assume to really use that config. and if something wrong happens i will post to record this information.
Thanks! =]

Comment: Well, now it's working. I need to close something here? Thanks!

Comment: If you are overclocking and it is working now and wasn't before, it might be temperature related. If it were me and I needed the extra performance, instead of overclocking I would go to a more powerful processor ... possibly PIC32 or ARM. I don't know if Microchip offers any pin-compatible upgrades for your part or not.

Comment: If you have the answer to your question, you can answer it here and accept your own answer. This will serve to indicate to others that it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm used the true value of the entrance clock and it's working now. So the value of the FOSC to UART BaudRate calculus is the value of the crystall including the PLL modifications. In resume is the input value of the CPU.